# MySql 8.0 partitioning plugin enable failure

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-8.0

I'm new to MySql partitioning technique.According to technical documentation I have heard in order to do so, When execute

```
SHOW PLUGINS;
```

it should indicate as active in query results.But there is no partition word in the list.https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-partition.php

I have tried

> DWITH_PARTITION_STORAGE_ENGINE

in

> my.ini

file.According to this guide.[option_cmake_storage_engine_options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/source-configuration-options.html#option_cmake_storage_engine_options). But it didn't work.correctly. Mysql version is 8.0 community edition

Could you please give solution regarding on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning is now built into InnoDB, and not available to any other Engines.

What were you hoping to do with partitioning?

Comment: I have to partitioning huge number of records according to range partitioning.in order to do so,partitions plugin not configured in my.ini file.how can i configure that?

Comment: @IsuruDhananjayaRanaweera - Where did you get the installation package, or are you compiling it yourself?  What exact version (8.0.xx)?  Please rovide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  ((The problem you describe should not happen; I am fishing for more clues.))

Comment: Database is already created one.DB size is 2GB. That's why i need to get partitioning methods. range partitioning by date. That partitioning side query and stuff is ok to me. Only thing is, where should i place DWITH_PARTITION_STORAGE_ENGINE this statement in my.ini file.

Comment: MySql Version is 8.0.17.  from this link   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/